# FML is not installed, you cannot connect to this server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I have a linux ubuntu Tekkitlite server setup. I have it running when when I use the new launcher for minecraft 1.2.1 set to 1.4.7 all I get is logging in, then straight to that error. "FML is not installed, you cannot connect to this server".

Minecraft Launcher 1.2.1
Tekkitlite 0.6.5

Please help!?

Comment: FML is the "Forge Mod Loader" However, it is odd that such an error may pop-up. Maybe you could try reinstalling the launcher

Answer (score 1):

Tekkit Lite is a pure Forge-based modpack. Unlike a CraftBukkit server, where you can use an unmodified client to connect to a server with plugins, a Forge server will only accept connections from Minecraft clients with matching mods. To connect to a Tekkit Lite server, you need to have the Tekkit Lite modpack installed in the Minecraft client you're trying to connect with.

The easiest way to do this is simply to launch Tekkit Lite in the Tekkit launcher. It will ask for your login, download a fresh Minecraft copy to a separate location from your regular Minecraft install, and install the whole Tekkit Lite modpack for you automatically. Then it's just connect and play.